# MVCContrib Pager in Razor encodes HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, pager

I have following code

```
@Html.Pager((IPagination)Model.FoundUsers).Last("<span class=\"last\">&nbsp</span>").First("<span class=\"first\">&nbsp</span>").Next("<span class=\"next\">&nbsp</span>").Previous("<span class=\"prev\">&nbsp</span>")
```

But it renders encoded and shows `<span class="next">` on page.

I tried to used Html.Raw as suggested in [Problem with razor view and mvccontrib grid pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558957/problem-with-razor-view-and-mvccontrib-grid-pagination) or [How to make a pager with MVCContrib and Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557139/how-to-make-a-pager-with-mvccontrib-and-razor)

but it still does not work for me.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any answers please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume that you are using MvcContrib v2 with Mvc4 (or possibly Mvc3)?

Either manually download the newer libraries from http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com or use the Raw method. So instead of this:

```
@Html.Pager((IPagination)Model.FoundUsers).Last("<span class=\"last\">&nbsp</span>").First("<span class=\"first\">&nbsp</span>").Next("<span class=\"next\">&nbsp</span>").Previous("<span class=\"prev\">&nbsp</span>")
```

You would instead have:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Pager((IPagination)Model.FoundUsers).Last("<span class=\"last\">&nbsp</span>").First("<span class=\"first\">&nbsp</span>").Next("<span class=\"next\">&nbsp</span>").Previous("<span class=\"prev\">&nbsp</span>"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's because I am working in VB, but I had to get the appropriate string from the Pager object:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Pager(Model).ToString)
```

I'm using MvcContrib 2.0.95 with MVC 3.